# Character Pointers and Space Searching

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have this very simple lab task to do, where all I need to do is print out the characters in a string twice, unless it's a space.

For a reason I can't seem to figure out, the "echoString" function is looping infinity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){

char* rhyme1 = "Hey Diddle diddle the Cat and the fiddle";
char rhyme2[265];
strncpy (rhyme2, "The Cow Jumped Over The Moon", sizeof(rhyme2));
char wordList[8][100];

/*Q1: Length of the string rhyme?*/
printf("Length: %d", strlen(rhyme1) );

/*Q2: Print out each letter twice, except for the spaces*/
echoString(rhyme1);

}

void echoString ( char* pString ) {

while ( *pString != '\0' ) {

    if ( !isspace( *pString ) ) {
        printf("%s%s", *pString, *pString);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s", *pString);
    }
    pString++;
}
}
```

I get the feeling it's to do with how I'm incrementing the pointer, or the isspace function.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: Changed '/0' to '\0'. Feel dumb for not seeing that.

Comment: the null character is **'\0'** for starters

Comment: Changed that. I feel dumb. That didn't fix it sadly.

Comment: Listen to your compiler, you probably've got warnings for implicit declarations of `strncpy`, `strlen` and `echoString` (all incompatible), with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall` I get warnings for the wrong format strings of all `printf` calls and a warning for a multi-character constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **`\0`** is for the null-terminated character, not `/0`. Change `'/0'` to `'\0'`.
2. Use **`%c`** to print a `char`, not `%s`, which is for a `string` instead. Change all `%s` to `%c`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( *pString != '/0' )
```

is wrong as `\0` is the Null character not `/0`.So change that to

```
while ( *pString != '\0' ) {
```

Then,

```
printf("%s%s", *pString, *pString);
```

is also wrong as you want each character twice.Change it to

```
printf("%c%c", *pString, *pString);
```

Do the same for

```
printf("%s", *pString);
```

So,your program should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>   //for strlen
#include <ctype.h>

void echoString(char*); //function prototype
int main(){

char* rhyme1 = "Hey Diddle diddle the Cat and the fiddle";
char rhyme2[265];
strncpy (rhyme2, "The Cow Jumped Over The Moon", sizeof(rhyme2));
char wordList[8][100];

/*Q1: Length of the string rhyme?*/
printf("Length: %d\n", strlen(rhyme1) );

/*Q2: Print out each letter twice, except for the spaces*/
echoString(rhyme1);
return 0;   
}

void echoString ( char* pString ) {

while ( *pString != '\0' ) {                 //\0 is NULL not /0

    if ( !isspace( *pString ) ) {
        printf("%c%c", *pString, *pString);  //%c for a character
    }
    else {
        printf("%c", *pString);              //%c for a character
    }
    pString++;
}
}
```